# Metadata - Case Search Layout

Tags: case, metadata, eclipse

In our project we have made couple of changes in the Search Layout of Case object.

[image: Search Layout]

Can anyone tell me where the metadata reside for this Search Layout in package explorer (Eclipse) hierarchy ?

I did not see the Search Layouts in the "layouts" folder though :(

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of the "CustomObject" type. If you retrieve "CustomObject" with either a wildcard or the name of your object, it will include the search layouts. Also, to modify such layouts, you must have version 27.0 or higher of the API. Please see the [CustomObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customobject.htm) page, as well as the related link on SearchLayouts.

Comment: Thanks resolved my issue.Just want to add that "Case" being a standard object , <searchLayout> will be available in "Object" folder in the metadata hierarchy not Custom object :)..Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @RisingPhoenix Using the IDE, yes, it splits them out, but if you're using the Metadata API, it'll be called a CustomObject. I apologize for not being clearer on that.